# how to find out my exact geographical location(lat , lng or bssid) , python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, location, python-3.6, userlocation

I need to know the exact location of the device on which the script is running (windows)

tried so:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client('Api KEY')
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('Me')
print(geocode_result)

conclusion >>> []
```

and so too:

```
from geopy import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("Me")
print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
so tried

import geopy
g = geopy.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

(Does not provide an exact location)

Comment: How "exact" do you want?

Comment: As accurately as possible, about like Google maps